# How to prevent minus sign when using DecimalFormat?

Tags: java, sign, number-formatting

I am using a library that lets me configure the way numbers are formatted using a DecimalFormat pattern. I need to remove the minus symbol to show the absolute value of the numbers. I have tried both "0.00###;0.00###" and "0.00###;#" without success. I can choose any minus symbol (e.g. "0.00###;(0.00###)") but I can't have no sign at all?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions,

Tom

Comment: Could you not simply do `Math.abs(double)` before passing it to the `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: Probably there is no format spec that gives you the absolute value of the number for the same reason why there is no format spec that gives you its square root or its logarithm.  Why not pass in Math.abs(n)?

Comment: Do you need to parse or just format? If the latter, and all you have is a pattern, you can put some dummy character like `\u2060` (zero-width joiner).

Comment: It is for formatting only so it's a good idea. The formatted result ends up in a XML tag value. I'll have to test if the XML file is valid with either a zero-width joiner or a space at the beginning of the numeric field. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use "0.00###; 0.00###" (notice the space after the semicolon) the negative sign will not be displayed.

Answer (score 7):

why can't you call [Math.abs()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs%28int%29) before formatting your number?

```
int myNum = -123;
myNum = Math.abs(myNum);
System.out.println(myNum); // 123
```

Comment: I have access to the source code but I cannot change it myself due to its license. I have only access to a configuration file where I can set the number format pattern. If there is no way to do it with a pattern, I'll request it as a new feature but it will take a while.

Answer (score 4):

If you really can't use absolute values with `Math.abs` as mentionned in other answers, you could change the minus sign in the [DecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) of your `DecimalFormat`. Beware that you need to set back the value into your `DecimalFormat`since it returns a different instance when calling [getDecimalFormatSymbols](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#getDecimalFormatSymbols%28%29).

You could also use [DecimalFormat.setNegativePrefix("")](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html#setNegativePrefix%28java.lang.String%29) as kdgregory commented.

Comment: +1 for the right idea, although there's an easier solution: `DecimalFormat.setNegativePrefix()`

Comment: I'll suggest this solution to the library developers. They could do that when a number format pattern has a negative subpattern without any symbol other than 0 or # at its beginning. I wish it was the default behavior of DecimalFormat.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not what you want, but why not use Math.abs() and simply do:

```
new DecimalFormat("0.00###").format(Math.abs(value))
```