# How to remove negative symbol for numeric value using spark sql command?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, command, symbols

How to remove negative symbol for numeric value using spark sql command?

Comment: Simply `ABS(numcol)`?

Answer (score 0):

[format_number](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/sql/index.html#format_number) can be used to control the output of numeric columns. And following [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38608030/2129801) we can omit the minus sign for negative values:

```python
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

df=spark.createDataFrame([[1.1],[-2.2]],['col'])
df.withColumn("formatted", f.expr("format_number(col, '0.00###; 0.00###')")).show()
```

Output:

```
+----+---------+
| col|formatted|
+----+---------+
| 1.1|     1.10|
|-2.2|     2.20|
+----+---------+
```

In a plain SQL environment (without PySpark)

```sql
select col, format_number(col, '0.00###; 0.00###') from <tablename>
```

returns the same result.